# Continuity of positive mappings

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

I wish to answer the following question

> Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of real continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$. A mapping $L: C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ is said to be positive if $L(f) \geqslant 0$ for each $f \in C[0,1]$ with $f \geqslant 0$, and linear if $L(a f+b g)=a L(f)+b L(g)$ for all functions $f, g \in C[0,1]$ and constants $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.
> (i) Let $L_n: C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ be a sequence of positive, linear mappings such that $L_n(f) \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ for the three functions $f(x)=1, x, x^2$. Prove that $L_n(f) \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ for every $f \in C[0,1]$.

Also I should say that the question did say that I am not allowed to use any version of the Stone-Weistrass theorem.

---

**Thoughts and attempts:** I realise that the positity condition tells us that if $f \leq g$ then $L (f) \leq  L (g)$. I was able to get some bounds
\begin{align*}
f_{\text{min}} \leq  \lim_{n \to \infty} L_n(f) \leq f_{\text{max}}.
\end{align*}
This should gurantee that I can find some subsequence that converges, however, I can not prove that it converges to $L (f)$.

I tried to prove something simipler, first do it for all polynomials and hope to get insight. However, I get stuck with the simplest that is non trivial: $x^3$. I do not think I can appproximate it uniformly via linear combination of $1,x,x ^{2}$.

**Question:** How do I approach this?

Comment: This is Korovkin's Theorem. All proof's I know are a bit tricky. A rather elegant proof can be found in a paper of Uchiyama: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3647883?seq=1

Comment: This is interseting - this should be a straight forward problem taking no more than 10 minutes as it is from a past paper on a course I am taking. Perhaps this was lectured that year.

Comment: Maybe there were some preparations in the course. Or there is a much simpler proof that I don't know.